# Eclipse: Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8

I get this error while trying to execute Tomcat 8.0.

[Error Windows](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20https://imgur.com/eWpPjAA)

This is my console output:

[Console output](https://textuploader.com/di4p6)

Can someone help me please?

Comment: It's better to actually add the text from errors and output to your question. That way if the link you added ever goes dead, the information is preserved in StackOverflow. It also prevents anyone trying to help answer your question from having to go to an outside side.

Comment: It looks you  are having an outdated web application referenced in your Tomcat embeded server. Try cleaning work directory from server panel

Comment: You seriously need to upgrade. That version of Tomcat was released more than 4 years ago. [Security vulnerabilities abound!](https://tomcat.apache.org/security-8.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to the log file, your deployment directory `C:\Users\Utente\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Pizza_LAST2` is not valid for some reason. That is, it is neither a directory nor a (WAR) file.

Does that path exist? Perhaps Eclipse is confused.